# Como configurar a String de conexão no App.config?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, app.config

Gostaria de montar usando as String salvas: `InstanciaSQLServer`, `UserSQL` e `PWSQL`, é possivel isso?

Exemplo do meu `app.config`

```
<configSections>


    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
        <-section name="BancoDeHoras.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6" />
</startup>    
<userSettings>
    <BancoDeHoras.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="InstanciaSQLServer" serializeAs="String">
            <value />
        </setting>
        <setting name="UserSQL" serializeAs="String">
            <value />
        </setting>
        <setting name="PWSQL" serializeAs="String">
            <value />
        </setting>
    </BancoDeHoras.Properties.Settings>
</userSettings>
<connectionStrings>
  <add
    name="conection"
    connectionString ="Data Source =[InstanciaSQLServer]; Initial Catalog = BancoDeHoras; User id = [UserSQL]; pwd=[PWSQL]"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Amigo, seja bem vindo a comunidade, sugiro, que leia nossa FAQ, de como fazer uma pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  , pois sua pergunta não esta clara, e assim fica dificil ajudar

Comment: @RonivaldoRoner: Como complemento: The Connection Strings Reference - https://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e5ae2b18-0795-49e8-a274-c3d52eccb8b3/connection-string-in-a-wpf-application?forum=wpf

Comment: O que eu gostaria de fazer é usar os valores salvos nas strings para montar a string de conexão. Exemplo: string conexao_BD = Data Source = [InstanciaSQLServer; Initial Catalog = BancoDeHoras; User id = [UserSQL]; pwd=[PWSQL];

Comment: Fiz correção no codigo de exemplo, qual a forma correta de escrever essa connectionString?

Comment: Resolvi o problema de uma outra forma. Não criei a String de Conexão no XML app.Config, criei ela direto na classe responsável por fazer a conexão. Dessa forma minha string ficou da seguinte forma: private static string conexao_DB = $@"Data Source = {Properties.Settings.Default.InstanciaSQLSERVER}; Initial Catalog = BancoDeHoras; User id = {Properties.Settings.Default.UserSQL}; pwd={Properties.Settings.Default.PWSQL}";    ---- Não sei se é a maneira correta de se fazer, mas foi a única que consegui até o momento.

Comment: Está utilizando `EntityFramework`?

Answer (score 2):

Seu código

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add
    name="conection"
    connectionString ="Data Source =[InstanciaSQLServer]; Initial Catalog = BancoDeHoras; User id = [UserSQL]; pwd=[PWSQL]"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Exemplo, vamos dizer que temos uma instancia do SQLEXPRESS que contem um banco de dados de nome TESTE com usuario: sa , senha: 123456

Sua instancia SQLEXPRESS corresponde ao seu servidor remoto ou local.

Vai ficar assim:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add
    name="conection"
    connectionString ="Data Source =SQLEXPRESS ; Initial Catalog = TESTE; User id = SA; pwd=123456"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

O seu código está certo, só faltou vc alterar os campos. Um ótimo site para você conferir os tipos de conexões existente https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2014/

Comment: Essa era a questão, não posso entrar com Data Source, Usuario e senha direto no código pois isso pode variar de acordo com cada instalação. Resolvi, salvando em propriedades. assim o usuario só vai informar isso no primeiro acesso ao sistema, inserindo Instancia Usuario e Senha da instancia SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o problema de uma outra forma. 
Não criei a String de Conexão no `XML` `app.Config`, criei ela direto na classe responsável por fazer a conexão. Dessa forma minha string ficou assim:

```
private static string conexao_DB = $@"Data Source = {Properties.Settings.Default.InstanciaSQLSERVER}; 
Initial Catalog = BancoDeHoras; 
User id = {Properties.Settings.Default.UserSQL}; 
pwd={Properties.Settings.Default.PWSQL}";
```

Não sei se é a maneira correta de se fazer, mas foi a única que consegui até o momento.

Comment: Existe uma forma muito fácil de criares a tua connectio string, apos isso é so abrires a tag `<connectionstrin>`.

Começas por criar um ficheiro txt e guardares. Após isso, gravas o ficheiro com extensão  .UDL (Universal Data Link). Experimenta